# Translation using mouse for rgl plot

Tags: mouse, rgl

I could not find any way to translates a rgl plot using mouse (mouseMode can not be set to a translate mode). Does anyone know how to do it ?
Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution from help of rgl.setMouseCallbacks

```
pan3d <- function(button) {
start <- list()

begin <- function(x, y) {
 start$userMatrix <<- par3d("userMatrix")
  start$viewport <<- par3d("viewport")
  start$scale <<- par3d("scale")
   start$projection <<- rgl.projection()
  start$pos <<- rgl.window2user( x/start$viewport[3], 1 - y/start$viewport[4], 0.5, 
                              projection=start$projection)
}

update <- function(x, y) {
 xlat <- (rgl.window2user( x/start$viewport[3], 1 - y/start$viewport[4], 0.5,
                         projection = start$projection) - start$pos)*start$scale
mouseMatrix <- translationMatrix(xlat[1], xlat[2], xlat[3])
par3d(userMatrix = start$userMatrix %*% t(mouseMatrix) )
}
rgl.setMouseCallbacks(button, begin, update)
cat("Callbacks set on button", button, "of rgl device",rgl.cur(),"\n")
}
pan3d(3)
```